# Prime numbers the rank of which is also a prime.

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

$127$ has an interesting property:
It is the $31$st prime number and its rank ($31$) is also a prime.
$31$ is the $11$th prime so its rank is also a prime.
$11$ is also a prime number with a rank ($5$) that is also a prime.
$5$ is the 3rd prime number and and so its rank ($3$) is also a prime.
And finally $3$ is the $2$nd prime so its rank is also a prime...
Is there a name for primes whose rank (index in the prime series) is also a prime?
That is:

> If $a_i$ is the $i$th prime number, then $i$ is a also a prime.

How about numbers like $127$ where going down ranks of ranks always produce prime numbers (down to rank $2$ of course)?
The first $11$ :-) primes in this (infinite) series would be:

$3, 5, 11, 31, 127, 709, 5381, 52711, 648391, 9737333, 174440041, \dotsc$

Many thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This sequence is well-know at OEIS, namely sequence [A007097](https://oeis.org/search?q=5%2C+11%2C+31%2C+127%2C+709%2C+5381%2C+52711&language=german&go=Suche), where one can find a lot of information and references:
$$
1, 2, 3, 5, 11, 31, 127, 709, 5381, 52711, 648391, 9737333, 174440041, 3657500101, 88362852307, 2428095424619, 75063692618249, 2586559730396077, 98552043847093519, 4123221751654370051, 188272405179937051081, 9332039515881088707361, 499720579610303128776791, 28785866289100396890228041$$
The name is "Primeth recurrence": $a(n+1) = a(n)$-th prime.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly the info I was looking for...

Comment: Done! Thanks once more...

Comment: Does anyone here know if it's a finite sequence or if those are just the last ones someone bothered to calculate ?

Comment: It's clearly infinite - given `a(n) = p` you can always calculate `a(n+1)` as being the `p`-th prime.

Comment: OEIS says that $a(n)$ is the Matula-Goebel number of the rooted path tree on $n+1$ vertices. So the sequence is infinite.

Comment: $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} $ is asymptotic to $\log a_n;\quad a_{24}/a_{23}\approx  57.6\;\log a_{24}\approx 58.6$

Comment: Another relevant OEIS sequence: http://oeis.org/A288469

Answer (score 8):

Sloane's OEIS simply calls them ["prime-indexed primes."](http://oeis.org/A006450)

Some more common notation would be $p_i$ for the $i$th prime. Then we have the prime counting function $\pi(p_i) = i$ (this function is defined for *all* positive numbers).

Using these notations, we can write the sequence $$1, p_1, p_{p_1}, p_{p_{p_1}}, p_{p_{p_{p_1}}}, \ldots$$

This is [Wilson's primeth recurrence](http://oeis.org/A007097).

Although both the sequence of prime-indexed primes and Wilson's primeth recurrence are infinite sequences, the former can be said to be less "exclusive" than the latter. If we iterate the function $f(n) = p_{\pi(n)}$, we'll find that all prime-indexed primes eventually reach a nonprime, but only those in Wilson's primeth recurrence reach $1$ without any composite numbers along the way.